# Select two values from two different tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, they look like this:

```
Table 1
==========================
id_tab1 | worker | number
==========================
1       | Adam   | 123123
```

```
Table 2
==========================
id_tab2 | worker | number
==========================
1       | Adam   | 123456
```

They both don't have anything in common. Sometimes `worker` might be in both of them and I want to count every row from both tables and show them like:

```
===============================================
worker | count_numbers_tab1 | count_numbers_tab2
===============================================
Adam   |           1        |         1
```

I tried with `INNER JOIN` but it shows weird numbers.

EDIT 1:
As with Abhilekh answer I ended up with following query(real example):

```
SELECT druga_klasa.pracownik, COUNT(druga_klasa.numer_zlecenia), COUNT(zlewy_zlomy.numer_zlecenia) FROM druga_klasa
FULL JOIN zlewy_zlomy on druga_klasa.pracownik=zlewy_zlomy.pracownik 
GROUP BY pracownik;
```

and thats how real tables looks like

[image]
[image]

and I've got an error saying

```
Unknown column druga_klasa.pracownik in field list.
```

Comment: What "weird numbers" does it show?  What's the query you've tried.  You probably just need a `GROUP BY` or something.

Comment: If they "don't have anything in common," then how do you expect to `JOIN` them?  Maybe you need a `LEFT JOIN` instead?

Comment: I've tried something like this `SELECT COUNT(tab2.numbers), COUNT(tab1.numbers), worker FROM tab1 LEFT JOIN tab2 ON tab1.worker= tab2.worker GROUP BY worker`

Comment: And what results does that give?  That query obviously works with the rows you've shown.  Can you add other example rows where your query does not work?

Comment: @RocketHazmat it wasn't working, error was `The column worker in the field list is ambiguous'

Comment: That just means you need to say `table1.worker`, since after a `JOIN`, there are multiple `worker` fields.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by they both don't have anything in common?

```
SELECT table1.worker, COUNT(table1.number), COUNT(table2.number) FROM table1
INNER JOIN table 2 on table1.worker=table2.worker
GROUP BY worker;
```

But this will only work if the column worker is common to both.

Comment: What if they aren’t common? Can I show 0 or something?

Comment: What isn't common the values or the column itself?

Comment: Values of the column worker. For example if worker Adam has 1 row in tab1 and he doesn’t appear in tab 2 I would like to show 0 or null or something in column count_tab2

Comment: Use full join for that the, replace inner with full. That should then give you the right result. Wherever there is not a value, it will show as null.

Comment: I've edited question please check it out